# Puppet: Could not find class

Tags: puppet

About ready to pull out my hair - I have done this a few times with success, but now suddenly I am overlooking something.

`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find class profiles::base for <fqdn> on node <fqdn>`

The path look ok:

```
[root@adm-01 ~]# cat /etc/puppet/modules/profiles/manifests/base.pp
class profiles::base {
  include '::ntp'
}
```

The site manifest as well:

```
[root@adm-01 ~]# cat /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
node default {
}

node adm-01 {
  notify { "Test":  }
  include profiles::base
}
```

I have tried profiles::base as well as ::profiles::base

Environment looks sound:

```
[root@adm-01 ~]# puppet master --configprint modulepath
/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppet/environments/common:/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

If I omit the base module, it does return the notify test.
Sure I am missing something glaringly obvious....

Comment: Funnily enough it works if I move all the modules to /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules....
Why would it not run through the full module path?

Comment: Did you possibly have another version of the "profiles" module in the production environment or common modules?

Comment: Have you activated the `environmentpath` option? That will make the `modulepath` obsolete and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, on deeper investigation I saw the daemon silently complained about a cert. Still weird that changing the path fixed it, but I uninstalled all things foreman, re-installed, and now it works.... Very odd that the agent did not complain though, found the references in the production log only.